# what is google map's javascript load strategy

Tags: javascript

When I use google maps, I am interested in its implemention, so I use the firebug to inspect.

Then I found that its javascript loading strategy is rather interesting.  Take this page for example:

[The overlay example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple)

Then when I open this page first time, the following js are loaded:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/13b/main.js
https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/13b/%7Bcommon,map,util,poly%7D.js
https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/13b/%7Bonion,geometry%7D.js
```

But if I refresh the page(use the ctrl+f5), the following js are loaded:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/13b/main.js
```

However the page still works, the overlay is drawn in the map. But where is the poly.js and etc?

Also, can anyone tell me how to load the js by components? For exmaple the `common` `util` `poly` in the example.

What should I know when I write the different components?

Comment: the other javascript files are cached. that's why they don't load the second time

Comment: @hguser I have written a long answer about js asset injection and i'm probably answering a different set of questions for you than you want example, but i think it will help you, but if it isn't helpful, my apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** When poly.js loads, it passes a string to `google.maps.__gjsload___`.

Here's an excerpt:

`google.maps.__gjsload__('common', '\'use strict\';var Ai=isNa...`

The rest of the file is just the contents of that string.

My hunch is this function probably stores this string in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` so that it only has to be retrieved once.

**2.** Also, if you want to learn about loading js files as-needed, look into [**AMD**](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) and/or CommonJS:[**Modules**](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1).

A good imlementation of AMD (my preference) is [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

### Update

I did some poking around, and `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` do not appear to be being used on this page. I also can't duplicate your results. In Firebug, poly.js always loads for me. There may be some magic happening somewhere, but I don't see it.

However, it's entirely possible to store a string in `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` for retrieval without having to make an extra js call.

Comment: but the require.js will use the callback,that's to say the code to be ran should be put at the callback function,however,in the main.js I do not find any callback.

Answer (score 0):

> Also,any one can tell me how to load the js by components?

this touches on the topic of asynchronous javascript file loading. if you've ever used a language that has a way to "include" a file at any point in a script, you'll understand that javascript does not have this capability. because of that, there is this whole paradigm of "aysnc javascript addition" via script tag injection.

script tag injection: you dynamically make a script tag, and set its source to the file you need, and insert that tag into the DOM, and voila, a new file has been loaded and executed. With javascript heavy applications, this is common, especially when loading third party applications. Google does it alllll the time, just check out google analytics' include script for a good example of this.

Now, since this is a touchy and delicate type of coding to do, some "javascript component / module / asset loading"  frameworks have refined it and made it pretty stable. common.js, require.js, etc have all done good jobs at this.

> What should I know when I write the different components ?

For what you're doing with google maps, you don't really need to know much. but if you get into javascript module pattern development, you need to know this: make sure you protect your global namespace from being cluttered by your own variables, so encapsulate all of your work in closures when possible, and (recommended but not required) start them all with a `;` so they don't break each other if they get loaded out of order.